# UINavigationBar appearance for UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uidocumentinteraction

I have an iOS app written in swift that overrides the default navigation bar background in `AppDelegate`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let navBackgroundImage = UIImage(named: "navBck")
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(patternImage: navBackgroundImage)
}
```

In the app I want to use a `UIDocumentInteractionController` to display a PDF file the app generates.

```
let docInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: pdfURL!)
docInteractionController.delegate = self
docInteractionController.presentPreview(animated: true)
```

The problem is that the custom background I have does not seem supported and this crashes with the following error (which doesn't occur without the custom background in `AppDelegate`)

*Assertion failure in -[UICGColor encodeWithCoder:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3600.7.47/UIColor.m:1549
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Only RGBA or White color spaces are supported in this situation.'*

I am looking for the cleanest and simplest way to work around this by restoring an ARGB background to the navigation bar just for this operation. I have tried the below in my `UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate` implementation with no luck (crashes with the same error)

```
func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.darkGrey
    return self
}

func documentInteractionControllerDidEndPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController)
{
    let navBackgroundImage:UIImage! = UIImage(named: "navBck")
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(patternImage: navBackgroundImage)
}
```

Comment: Try setting the barTintColor prior to presenting the UIDocumentInteractionController.

Comment: Just tried, this gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

An excerpt from the documentation of UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate:

> // If preview is supported, this provides the view controller on which the preview will be presented.
>
> // This method is required if preview is supported.
>
> // **If presenting atop a navigation stack, provide the navigation controller in order to animate in a manner consistent with the rest of the platform.**
>
> @available(iOS 3.2, *)
>
> `optional public func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController`

Also, in my fresh project, I always used `navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor` instead of `UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor`.

**EDIT**: New example, with more understanding of UIDocumentInteractionController

**ViewController that presents the UIDocumentInteractionController**

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = getCustomTintColor
    }

    func getCustomTintColor() -> UIColor{
        let navBackgroundImage:UIImage! = UIImage(named: "navBck")
        return UIColor(patternImage: navBackgroundImage)
    }

    func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor. darkGrey
        return navigationController!
    }
    
    func documentInteractionControllerDidEndPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = getCustomTintColor
    }
```

To be honest, I also feel even the crash will not at all happen if you

1. Use `navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor` instead of `UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor`
2. Return navigationController in `documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview()`

**This way, your preview screen will also have the correct tint.**
*Please provide the image, so that I can check in my sample project(Or check for yourself in your code :) ).*

Comment: UIDocumentInteractionController does not extend UIViewController so I do not see how navigationController.pushViewController(docInteractionController, animated: true) can compile. Replacing it with docInteractionController.presentPreview(animated: true) fails as per my comment above

Comment: In my last sample project, I created a random VC and checked. Now, I've validated by actually opening a pdf.

Comment: I believe a lot of the problem lies in UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor, I used navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor throughout and it works fine for me. I didn't try with your colors, I just used green and cyan in my project

Comment: If possible, could you share the image you're using, I wanna check why I cant set the navigation bar for the UIDocumentInteractionController's preview controller's navigation bar.